# Export form data to excel is not working on newly upgraded site

Tags: wffm

My site is upgraded from 7.5 to 8.1, I deployed my site on the CM enviroment and now the export form data to excel for any WFFM form is not working.

The request:

```
http://MySite/api/sitecore/ExportFormData/Download?file=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\website\temp\i0r0xknb.ssw&format=1
```

returns a 404 not found response.

The same functionality is working fine on my development environment.

Any Ideas what cause this error?

[image]

Comment: Can you compare the files from your CM environment and your dev environment? Especially bin and wffm folders. Might be some file did not get transferred correctly.

Comment: I couldn't find any difference..

Comment: Sometimes few functionalities in sitecore don't work in some browsers. Please try in a different browser to confirm this is not the browser issue.

Comment: All browsers produce the same behavior

Comment: it is often when servers have more strict write permission rather than dev environments. Check that IIS process have write permissions to "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MySite\website\temp\" folder