# How to view WFFM form response data in Sitecore

Tags: wffm

I am using WFFM with Sitecore SXA. I am seeing the responses as in the image. But, exact form data is not shown. How can we see the exact data?

The image shows the reports in the form of bar chart.
But I want it to show form data filled by the users.
How can we achieve that?

[image]

Comment: You can use `Actions-> Export to Excel / XML` to view detailed submission data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Sitecore does not include a GUI for viewing WFFM form responses. However, Sitecore does provide the ability to *export* your WFFM form response data to Excel for easy viewing, or to XML for viewing in another application.

[image: image of export feature from question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/3309/423]

*(above image was copied from [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/3309/423))*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for the GUI only. Export action is working fine.